# Enabling service using systemctl on a mounted OS/device

Tags: mount, services, systemctl

I am trying to create a bootable USB stick that will contain the Raspbian OS and will have some extra applications and services enabled.

What I normally do is flash the image of Raspbian OS on to the USB stick, boot the USB from the Raspberry Pi, copy my applications/files, copy the service file `sudo cp srcPath/app.service /etc/systemd/system/app.service` and run `sudo systemctl enable app`.

Is it possible after flashing the image of the OS to the USB stick, mount the rootfs partition of the USB stick to `/media/usb/rootfs`, copy the service file to `/media/usb/rootfs/etc/systemd/system/app.service` to enable the service on the Raspbian OS and not on my actual system which I used to flash the image?

Comment: Just a small note, if there is any solution to do the above without using the `systemctl` command that is also acceptable answer, as long as it has the same behaviour of running `sudo systemctl enable app` on the Raspbian OS.

Comment: Running the command `sudo ln -s /etc/systemd/system/app.service /media/usb/rootfs/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/app.service` seem to work fine; although I don't know if that is an improper way to achieve what I want and if there will be any side-effects by doing it that.